# Decrease the response time from MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

I am using datatable to display all the records I am getting from database. Currently in the table I have around 8000 records and 17 fields in the table. So when it loads in my PHP page it takes long time to display. So Can anyone please help me to reduce the time.

Regards
Sagar

Comment: Better use server side processing of datatable.

Comment: tried but not affecting much.

Comment: @SagarChhaniyara refer below

Answer (score 2):

You should use ajax as a datasource for datatable because your records are going to be increased periodically and you can not minimize the response time of selecting records from table that much. Here is the reference for ajax data scource. https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: Why it's not effective? Are you loading data on pagination call?

Comment: Have you added pagination? Its the most effective one for your problem.

Comment: I think pagination is done by datatable automatically.

Comment: No you have to paginate using the AJAX parameters so that it will reflect only those data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to optimize your query in following way:

1. Instead of `Select * from ....` specify only required field like `SELECT id, name .. FROM TABLENAME`
2. Use page navigation so that 8000 records need not to be fetched. If you display 8000 records on a same page, it will not be user friendly.
3. Try to minimize the external js and css upto possible ways.

After all, you can't expect the same response time of the page which will have only 10 records.

Answer (score -1):

Use datatable server-side processing method for reduce response time

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.